# http errors using travis for R packages

Tags: r, http, travis-ci, httr

I have a R package to connect R to different open data APIs (ie PXWEB API:s).

The travis builds works perfectly for the builds when no calls to an example web api is conducted (NOT_CRAN="false" in build matrix).

But when I include tests that also test api calls using http to a specific pxweb server I sometimes get "No internet connection" error in the tests. If I try to rerun the build the test sometimes passes (and sometimes not). I

The package and travis builds can be found here:

https://github.com/ropengov/pxweb

https://travis-ci.org/rOpenGov/pxweb

Comment: In order to get it accepted on CRAN, you'll need to have all tests succeed even without an internet connection. This means making all examples and tests conditional on a successful connection.

Comment: I know, thats why I have two test suites, one NOT_CRAN = 'true' with a full test suite (with http) and one NOT_CRAN = 'false' where all these tests are skipped. The problem is that I want to have the best of both worlds. Tests that is accepted on CRAN and a larger test suite on travis.

Comment: I get the same errors... Travis sometimes seems to ban outgoing connections. If it works locally, I would set up a mock page for tests or else just use other CI service that has no problem with those connections. Try also with customer support, they are usually helpful.